# C++ Identifying Secondary and Tertiary Displays in Pixels

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have used `SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN`, `SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN` determines the TOTAL width and height, and  `SM_CXSCREEN`, `SM_CYSCREEN` determines the width and height of the primary monitor. As well as `SM_CMONITORS` to see all the active displays.

Is there a way to determine the height and weight in pixels of the secondary and tertiary display monitors using `GetSystemMetrics()`?

For example, if the Secondary Display was identified, I would like to see returned values of x = 2560, y = 1080, when I debug.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows API function that you are looking for is [`EnumDisplayMonitors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162610.aspx).

- Call `EnumDisplayMonitors` passing a [callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145061.aspx) function.
- The [callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145061.aspx) function will be called for each attached monitor.
- The callback function is provided with a handle to the monitor (can be used to obtain further information) and a `RECT` with the coordinates of the monitor.